# Create a key value pair for both the current key and value

Tags: javascript, lodash, key-value

I currently have an array of simple objects:

```
data = [{ "alternative hip hop": 3 }, { "escape room": 4 }, ...]
```

...to which I'd like to transform into

```
newData = [
    { "name": "alternative hip hop", "count": 3 },
    { "name": "escape room", "count" 4 }
]
```

Is this doable with a map? I've failed at figuring out how to do so with one.

lodash responses are welcome as well

Comment: Can you guarantee that each object in the original data array will only have one key-value pair?

Comment: Yep! Only one key-val per object

Comment: I will say, your structure for `data` is a bit odd.  It might be worth looking into whether you can avoid that sort of data structure in the first-place.

Comment: Agreed. Its just a temporary holder for some json I needed to transform.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming each item in the data has a single key/value pair, you'd want:

```
data.map(obj => {
    const key = Object.keys(obj)[0]; //Just get the first key we find
    return {
        name: key,
        count: obj[key]
    };
})
```

Comment: It always amazes me how simple this problem is for more experienced developers. Like I could've found a solution, but it would've taken me at least half an hour of experimenting.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!
In my attempts I missed adding the [0] to Object.keys.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I didn't write it false on my Mobile, but here is a way:

```
let newData = data.map(e => {
    for(let key in e) {
       return { 
           name: key,
           count: e[key]
       };
    }
});
```

Comment: I fixed a bit of indentation, added a bit of whitespace, looks like this would work, too.

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with loadsh, but with javascript you can do the following:

```
var data = [{ "alternative hip hop": 3 }, { "escape room": 4 }]
var newData = [];

data.forEach((item)=>{ //loop over the array
  Object.keys(item) //get the object keys
    .map((keyName)=>{  //loop over each key
        newData.push({name:keyName, count:item[keyName]}) //insert it into the new array
     })
})
console.log(newData)
```